# Помогите разобраться с флексом

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Подскажите в чем я ошибаюсь.
у меня два меню которые я хочу разместить горизонтально. Они находятся в блоке, которому я дал тоже свойство flex, как и блокам с меню.
Как только я начинаю устанавливать отступы между элементами меню, то это меню начинает  ВЫЛАЗИТЬ [image: введите сюда описание изображения] за пределы утановленного пространства для этого элемента заданного автоматически в блоке родителя. Попытки растянуть это место никак не полчаются. как это сделать. Что при добавлении отступов, блок просто растягивался. При добавлении flex:1; [image: введите сюда описание изображения]блок добавляется но начинает занимать ВСЁ пустое пространство, что тоже мне не нужно. Помогите пожалуйста. вот фрагмент кода

```html
 <style>
        .footer__soc-menu,
        .footer__wrapper,
        .footer__menu {
            display: flex;
        }
        .footer__wrapper{
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        li{
            padding-left: 7%;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer__wrapper">
            <ul class="footer__menu">
                <li><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cookies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Brand Guide</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="footer-social">
                <div class="social__title">Our social media:</div>
                <ul class="footer__soc-menu">
                    <li><a href=""><img src="./source/img/pic_social/tw.png" alt="social_pic"></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><img src="./source/img/pic_social/fb.png" alt="social_pic"></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><img src="./source/img/pic_social/insta.png" alt="social_pic"></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><img src="./source/img/pic_social/in.png" alt="social_pic"></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><img src="./source/img/pic_social/yt.png" alt="social_pic"></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><img src="./source/img/pic_social/tt.png" alt="social_pic"></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><img src="./source/img/pic_social/tg.png" alt="social_pic"></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><img src="./source/img/pic_social/vk.png" alt="social_pic"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: похоже ответов на этот вопрос ни у кого нет(

Comment: т.е. Вы хотите, чтобы вверху и слева и справа у Вас было меню, при этом, чтобы левое и правое меню находились на одном уровне по высоте, верно?